# How to handle attributes with different shapes to train a neural network

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network

Initially, I have a data set with 2 attributes :

- a regular attribute called "feature". Each element of this attribute is a matrix of shape = (13,87)
- the label (the feature I want to predict)

This dataset is available by following this link :

[dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mHMzBb4cKRqKA_btepTPaOxaMdf_xP-T)

I builded a neural network using this dataset by executing this code :

```
    import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import to_categorical

num_rows = 13
num_columns = 87
num_channels = 1
seed = 2001

path = 'C:/Users/lione/OneDrive/Bureau/Lionel/LDK_360/Projets/Fexy-consign/Data/cleaned_dataset.xlsx'

featuresdf = pd.read_excel(path)

X = np.array(featuresdf.feature.tolist())
y = np.array(featuresdf.label.tolist())

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
cvscores = []

X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], num_rows, num_columns, num_channels)

for train, test in kfold.split(X, y):
  print(X[train].shape)


  le = LabelEncoder()
  yy = to_categorical(le.fit_transform(y)) 
  num_labels = yy.shape[1]
  num_labels = 5
  filter_size = 2

# Construct model 
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(num_rows, num_columns, num_channels), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

  model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
  # Compile model
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  #Fit the model
  model.fit(X[train], yy[train], epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
  # evaluate the model
  scores = model.evaluate(X[test], yy[test], verbose=2)
  print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
  cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
```

I performed some additionnal tests and I will add to this initial dataset several attributes.

These additional attributes contain one unique real value.

Thus the resulting dataset will look like that :

```
feature feature_1 feature_2 feature_3  label
[[...]]   1            2        3       class1
[[...]]   4            5        6       class2
   .      .            .        .         .
[[...]]   12           13       14       class5
```

My question are :

- how to handle a dataset with attributes which have different shapes ?

  - How should I modify my Python script to handle such dataset if it is feasible ?
  - Or should I train several models ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can train one single model but you have to readjust it. you need to have two input branches. the first one handles 3D data in order to apply convolution. the second branch deals with dense features that are the new features you create. I provide you a dummy example where I train this kind of model

```
# define param
n_sample = 100
num_rows = 13
num_columns = 87
num_channels = 1
n_new_features = 4
num_labels = 5

# define data
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,num_rows,num_columns,num_channels))
X_new = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,n_new_features))
y = np.random.randint(0,2, (n_sample,num_labels))

# conv part
inp = Input((num_rows,num_columns,num_channels))
x = Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(inp)
x = Flatten()(x)

# new dense part
inp_new = Input((n_new_features))
x_new = Dense(16, activation='relu')(inp_new)

# concat dense and conv
xx = Concatenate()([x,x_new])
out = Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax')(xx)

# define model
model = Model([inp,inp_new],out)
model.compile('adam','categorical_crossentropy')

model.fit([X,X_new], y, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Let me know if there are problem

Comment: Thanks you for your help @Marco Cerliani ! I currently collect some data to build the "new" attributes. When I finish this task (at the end of this week), I can use your script to build my neural network and I let you know if there are problem. Have a nice day ! Regards.

Comment: Great! My script is a simple tutorial you have to adapt and customize according to your needs. Don't forget to accept it as answer ;-)

Comment: is there any progress?

Comment: Thank you for your message @Marco Cerliani. I have been late in collecting and processing my additional data...but I tested your code and I have an error  : it is said "'int' object is not iterable" at the line "inp_new = Input((n_new_features))". I searched a solution on internet, but not I does not found a fix. Can you help me ?

Comment: I finally found a fix to the error I mentionned : I used "inp_new = Input(([n_new_features]))" instead of "inp_new = Input((n_new_features))"...By doing this your code works fine.

Comment: A priori I think that (after adaptation to my own use case) there is no reason that your code does not work with my future data. Thus, I will accept your solution as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Good job!